# How can I move the fastest?

Tags: loadout

Am I faster if I use sprint + dives,jumps or even powerjumps (jump after dive) while moving?

I do not trust my eyes on that one and therefore I ask.

Loadout wiki did not cover this.

My feeling tells me that the fastest way to move is sprint + dive.

Comment: The actual fastest movement would be while buffed with 'The Juice', but it's not really feasible to have somebody follow you around and continuously juice you.

Comment: thats just a coefficient which would not change the basic movement-pattern that is the fastest. But since my question header is quite general it is a good addition